# Custom URL Parameter in gRPC-Gateway Transcoding

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, proto, grpc-web, grpc-gateway

for example, I have this kind of proto definition:

```proto
service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
        get: "/hello"
      };
  }
}

message HelloRequest {
  repeated int32 ids = 1;
  repeated string categories = 2;
}

message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

when I use gRPC-gateway, based on transcoding above, you can request with this kind of query

```
localhost:8080/hello?ids=1&ids=2&categories=food&categories=drink
```

Is there any way to remap the url query parameters?

for example to become:

```
localhost:8080/hello?ids[]=1&ids[]=2
```

Can't find any on the documentation

Thanks.